# Samsung RC520 laptop and 2 bootable SSD drives

Tags: boot, laptop, ssd, bios

I have Samsung RC520 laptop, 4-5 years old. It originally had HDD 320GB,  DVD+/-RW drive and Windows 7. Last year I migrated Windows from HDD to Samsung 840 120GB SSD and old HDD was mounted as second, non-bootable drive (for data storage) in DVD bay using Raidsonic/IcyBox IB-AC642 adapter. It worked perfectly. Few months ago I migrated from Windows 7 to 10. No problems.

Now I need to use 2 operating system on this machine. I have second SSD drive - Intel 530 120GB - with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it. When I replace Samsung SSD (Win 10) with Intel (Ubuntu) laptop starts and runs Ubuntu without problems. But when I install both SSD drives together, no matter which as first and which in DVD bay adapter, laptop stops on initial screen (with Samsung logo) and nothing happens. I can't even enter BIOS. When I replace second SSD (in DVD bay) with old, non-bootable HDD, laptop starts with no problems, regardless of which SSD (Win or Ubuntu) was left inside.

BIOS has few options regarding discs and I try all combinations of UEFI and AHCI options. Result is always the same. I tried to upgrade BIOS, but Samsung BIOS app for this laptop model probably doesn't work on Win 10 ("Loading driver failed. Restart system.")

Any ideas? Is there any limit of connecting 2 bootable SSD to a laptop?

Comment: Problem is probably BIOS or laptop hardware related. I was able to update BIOS (from version 03FA to 08FA) after running update program in Windows 7 compatibility mode. After this update I can enter BIOS, both SSDs are detected, so it much better. However, first SSD doesn't boot automatically. If I don't press any key, laptop stops on Samsung logo screen. If I press Esc (which activates boot menu) I can choose first SSD and boot from it.

Comment: Since I not found a good solution, I gave up installation of 2 bootable drives, I deleted OEM partioon (25GB) from Windows disc, then shrunk Windows partition and installed Ubuntu on free space of Windows disc. Now everything works perfect. Some data is kept on mechanical HDD, which is used as a second drive.